# What is the lowest and highest number of

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm

I'm building a basic pagination bar to separate posts into pages. I have 3 numeric values:

```
$posts_per_page
$total_pages
$clicked_page_number
```

So for example, I have `31` posts. And my `$posts_per_page` value is `15`, which means that `$total_pages` becomes `3`.

My question is, how do I calculate the *lowest* and *highest* post number *of the selected page*? In either javascript or PHP.

To explain this, using the values above, if user clicks on page `2`, then the lowest post number is `16` and the highest post number is `30`.

Comment: This may be some entry-level stuff but my skills are a bit rusty. =)

Comment: Okay, I am sure you mean, 31 posts right?
If you have 31 pages, than your total pages is 31, not 3.

and your min pages is 1, if total pages is > 0, and otherwise max is total pages.

if you want to know the total post count, its total pages * post pr page.

Comment: Seriously it's not about programming, it's a simple math.

Comment: maths ... postsPerPage * pageNumber is the highest post ... subtract (postsperpage - 1)  and you get the lowest number

Comment: @MortenBork No. If I have 31 posts, and 15 posts in each page, then total pages is 3. =)

Comment: indeed, but you **SAID**  `I have 31 pages` in the question

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Please correct your statement. You have written 31 PAGES!

Comment: Ah got it, sorry it has been fixed!

Comment: I've edit the pages vs. posts confusion which OP had in their question.

Comment: `$lowest = (($clicked_page_number - 1) * $posts_per_page) + 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the highest, just multiply the page number by the posts per page. The min check is to catch the final page max (for example, if the last page only has 3 in it).

```
var highest = Math.min(totalPosts, clickedPageNumber * postsPerPage)
```

To get the lowest, it must be the one after the multiple of the previous pages posts per page (as every valid page must have the same min).

```
var lowest = (clickedPageNumber - 1) * postsPerPage + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is, as someone else mentioned, basic maths, and has nothing to do with programming. However, here goes:

```
$min_post_number = ($clicked_page_number - 1) * $posts_per_page + 1;
$max_post_number = $clicked_page_number * $posts_per_page;
$max_post_number = $max_post_number > $total_posts ? $total_posts : $max_post_number;
```

Comment: The maximum should be `$max_post_number = $clicked_page_number * $posts_per_page;`

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Thanks, I fixed it. Also, I added a check in case the max posts doesn't go to the end of the page.

Comment: @Henrik, no that is wrong, and doesn't account for the last page.

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectedPageBoundaries($clicked_page_number){
     global $posts_per_page;
     $rtn = array();
     $rtn['lower'] = (int_val($clicked_page_number/$posts_per_page)*$posts_per_page);
     $rtn['upper'] = $rtn['lower'] + $posts_per_page;
     return $rtn;
}
```

something like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$lowest  = 1 + $posts_per_page * ($clicked_page_number - 1);
$highest = $posts_per_page * $clicked_page_number;
```